# Checking if row exists in Table with 10 million rows

Tags: sql, laravel-5, redis

I'm importing XML file values to DB and end up checking if the row already exists, this takes a lot of time as the table has around 10million rows. For a file to import it takes roughly 90 seconds, on empty database 4secs. I'm checking if the row exists with laravel eloquent
exists() method. I want to reduce this time as much as possible, if im importing 10k files, it takes DAYS. I was thinking of saving inserted rows in redis cache and checking if row exists from cache, but if for some reason cache is cleared I don't want to make duplicates in database. Is there anything better than redis?

Comment: Why would Redis be cleared?

Comment: @GuyKorland I havent used redis before, but from my understanding, it works like cache. So for example, if the server restarts or service crashes all the data in cache would be gone, no? I read that there are some ways to save cache after each query, but doesnt the speed suffer from it?

Answer (score 0):

You should use exist check using DBMS and Redis like

```
for row in file do
  if row not in redis then
    if row not in RDMS then
      insert_row_in_RDBMS
      insert_row_in_redis 
    else
      insert_row_in_redis 
    end
  end
end
```

Using this you can reduce the query time, though this will only help when you have many duplicate rows in files.